# Copiar y pegar filas de un DataGrid a otro DataGrid WPF y SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, wpf

En lo que me deseo que me ayuden, comunidad de expertos, es en poder copiar y pegar registros de un DataGrid a otro. Cada DataGrid tiene sus registros almacenados en una Base de datos. Para mi DataGrid-A e hecho los siguientes Stored Procedures para AñadirRegistros, EditarRegistros, EliminarRegistros y para copiar y pegar Registros, respectivamente...

```
    CREATE PROC InsertarFactura
@RazonSocial NVARCHAR(150),
@NombreProveedor NVARCHAR(250),
@OC NVARCHAR(100),
@Facturas NVARCHAR(100),
@FormaPago NVARCHAR(10),
@FechaRecibido NVARCHAR(100),
@FechaPago NVARCHAR(100),
@MonedaMXN DECIMAL(18,2),
@MonedaUSD DECIMAL(18,2),
@Notas NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
INSERT INTO Pendientes VALUES(@RazonSocial, @NombreProveedor, @OC, @Facturas, @FormaPago, @FechaRecibido, @FechaPago, @MonedaMXN, @MonedaUSD, @Notas)
GO


CREATE PROC EditarFactura
@RazonSocial NVARCHAR(150),
@NombreProveedor NVARCHAR(250),
@OC NVARCHAR(100),
@Facturas NVARCHAR(100),
@FormaPago NVARCHAR(10),
@FechaRecibido NVARCHAR(100),
@FechaPago VARCHAR(100),
@MonedaMXN DECIMAL(18,2),
@MonedaUSD DECIMAL(18,2),
@Notas NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
UPDATE Pendientes SET RazonSocial=@RazonSocial, NombreProveedor=@NombreProveedor, OC=@OC, Facturas=@Facturas, FormaPago=@FormaPago, FechaRecibido=@FechaRecibido, FechaPago=@FechaPago, MonedaMXN=@MonedaMXN, MonedaUSD=@MonedaUSD, Notas=@Notas
GO


CREATE PROC EliminarFactura
@Facturapro NVARCHAR(100)
AS
DELETE FROM Pendientes WHERE Facturas=@Facturapro
GO

CREATE PROC FacturaPagada
@RazonSocial NVARCHAR(150),
@NombreProveedor NVARCHAR(250),
@OC NVARCHAR(100),
@Facturas NVARCHAR(100),
@Facturapro NVARCHAR(100),
@FormaPago NVARCHAR(10),
@FechaRecibido NVARCHAR(100),
@FechaPago NVARCHAR(100),
@MonedaMXN DECIMAL(18,2),
@MonedaUSD DECIMAL(18,2),
@Notas NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
INSERT INTO Pagadas VALUES(@RazonSocial, @NombreProveedor, @OC, @Facturas, @FormaPago, @FechaRecibido, @FechaPago, @MonedaMXN, @MonedaUSD, @Notas) SELECT RazonSocial, NombreProveedor, OC, Facturas, FormaPago, FechaRecibido, FechaPago, MonedaMXN, MonedaUSD, Notas FROM Pendientes WHERE Facturas=@Facturapro
GO
```

Después e creado mi cadena de conexión en mi proyecto WPF y dos clases. En mi primera clase e agregado objetos de acceso de datos(CD_Facturas.cs)

```
public class CD_Facturas
{
    private Conexion conexion = new Conexion();

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();


    public void Insertar(string RazonSocial, string NombreProveedor, string OC, string Facturas, string FormaPago, string FechaRecibido, string FechaPago, decimal MonedaMXN, decimal MonedaUSD, string Notas)
    {
        command.Connection = conexion.Connection();
        command.CommandText = "InsertarFactura";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RazonSocial", RazonSocial);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NombreProveedor", NombreProveedor);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OC", OC);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Facturas", Facturas);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormaPago", FormaPago);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaRecibido", FechaRecibido);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaPago", FechaPago);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MonedaMXN", MonedaMXN);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MonedaUSD", MonedaUSD);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notas", Notas);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        command.Parameters.Clear();
        conexion.CloseConnection();
    }

    public void Editar(string RazonSocial, string NombreProveedor, string OC, string Facturas, string FormaPago, string FechaRecibido, string FechaPago, decimal MonedaMXN, decimal MonedaUSD, string Notas)
    {
        command.Connection = conexion.Connection();
        command.CommandText = "EditarFacturas";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RazonSocial", RazonSocial);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NombreProveedor", NombreProveedor);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OC", OC);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Facturas", Facturas);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormaPago", FormaPago);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaRecibido", FechaRecibido);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaPago", FechaPago);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MonedaMXN", MonedaMXN);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MonedaUSD", MonedaUSD);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notas", Notas);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        command.Parameters.Clear();
        conexion.CloseConnection();
    }
    
    public void Eliminar(string Factura)
    {
        command.Connection = conexion.Connection();
        command.CommandText = "EliminarFactura";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Facturapro", Factura);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        command.Parameters.Clear();
        conexion.CloseConnection();
    }

public void InsertarPagadas(string RazonSocial, string NombreProveedor, string OC, string Facturas, string FormaPago, string FechaRecibido, string FechaPago, decimal MonedaMXN, decimal MonedaUSD, string Notas)
    {
        command.Connection = conexion.Connection();
        command.CommandText = "EditarFacturas";
        

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        conexion.CloseConnection();
    }

}
```

Mi segunda clase es para validar los registros(CN_Facturas.cs)

```
public class CN_Facturas
{
    private CD_Facturas facturaCD = new CD_Facturas();

    public void InsertarFactura(string RazonSocial, string NombreProveedor, string OC, string Facturas, string FormaPago, string FechaRecibido, string FechaPago, string MonedaMXN, string MonedaUSD, string Notas)
    {
        facturaCD.Insertar(RazonSocial, NombreProveedor, OC, Facturas, FormaPago, FechaRecibido, FechaPago, Convert.ToDecimal(MonedaMXN), Convert.ToDecimal(MonedaUSD), Notas);
    }

    public void EditarFactura(string RazonSocial, string NombreProveedor, string OC, string Facturas, string FormaPago, string FechaRecibido, string FechaPago, string MonedaMXN, string MonedaUSD, string Notas)
    {
        facturaCD.Editar(RazonSocial, NombreProveedor, OC, Facturas, FormaPago, FechaRecibido, FechaPago, Convert.ToDecimal(MonedaMXN), Convert.ToDecimal(MonedaUSD), Notas);
    }

    public void EliminarFactura(string Factura)
    {
        facturaCD.Eliminar(Factura);
    }

    public void FacturaPagada(string RazonSocial, string NombreProveedor, string OC, string Facturas, string FormaPago, string FechaRecibido, string FechaPago, string MonedaMXN, string MonedaUSD, string Notas)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Después codifique la funcion de cada buton. Añadir, Editar y Elimnar

```
private void btnAñadir_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (c.facturaRegistrada(Convert.ToString(txtFacturas.Text)) == 0)
        {
            if (Editar == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    facturaCN.InsertarFactura(cmbRazonS.Text, cmbNombreProveedor.Text, txtOC.Text, txtFacturas.Text, cmbFormaPago.Text, dateRecibido.Text, datePago.Text, txtMXN.Text, txtUSD.Text, txtNotas.Text);
                    MessageBox.Show("SE INSERTO CORRECTAMENTE");
                    limpiar();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No se inserto la factura: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Registro existente", "ERROR");
        }

        if (Editar == true)
        {
            try
            {
                facturaCN.EditarFactura(cmbRazonS.Text, cmbNombreProveedor.Text, txtOC.Text, txtFacturas.Text, cmbFormaPago.Text, dateRecibido.Text, datePago.Text, txtMXN.Text, txtUSD.Text, txtNotas.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("SE EDITO CORRECTAMENTE");
                limpiar();
                Editar = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo editar por: " + ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }


private void gridEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (facturasPendientesDG.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            AddFactura.AddNewFactura editarFactura = new AddFactura.AddNewFactura();
            editarFactura.Show();
            DataRowView datos = facturasPendientesDG.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
            if (datos != null)
            {
                Editar = true;
                editarFactura.cmbRazonS.Text = datos["RazonSocial"].ToString();
                editarFactura.cmbNombreProveedor.Text = datos["NombreProveedor"].ToString();
                editarFactura.txtOC.Text = datos["OC"].ToString();
                editarFactura.txtFacturas.Text = datos["Facturas"].ToString();
                editarFactura.cmbFormaPago.Text = datos["FormaPago"].ToString();
                editarFactura.dateRecibido.Text = datos["FechaRecibido"].ToString();
                editarFactura.datePago.Text = datos["FechaPago"].ToString();
                editarFactura.txtMXN.Text = datos["MonedaMXN"].ToString();
                editarFactura.txtUSD.Text = datos["MonedaUSD"].ToString();
                editarFactura.txtNotas.Text = datos["Notas"].ToString();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
        }
    }


    private void gridEliminar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView datos = facturasPendientesDG.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        if (datos != null)
        {
            idFactura = datos["Facturas"].ToString();
            facturaCN.EliminarFactura(idFactura);
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("ELIMINADO CORRECTAMENTE");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
        }
    }
```

Todos mis botones estan agregados en mi DataGrid, excepto el de Añadir nuevo registro. Sí se dan cuenta en todas mis clases aparece vacio donde deberia estar codificado para pasar mis filas de DataGrid a DataGrid. En eso es lo que deseo que me ayuden. Cada fila de mi DataGrid tiene un ButtonCheck que al momento de presionarlo debería pasar mi registro a mi DataGrid-B. Espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: Y basicamente cual es el problema? si sabes cargar un datagrid, sabes cargar el otro... De todo este codigo, no surge ningun problema en si... o por lo menos no queda claro porque no podes agregar el registro a la otra grilla.. ni siquiera sabemos como cargas las grillas....

Comment: El problema es que aun no tengo idea de como copiar y pegar los registro. E creado mi Stored Procedure únicamente, no tengo nada más

Comment: pero que tiene que el SP con cargar otra grilla?

Answer (score 0):

E encontrado la respuesta, muchas gracias por su apoyo. E hecho lo siguiente:
En mi clase CD_FACTURAS.cn ...

```
 public void InsertarPagadas(string RazonSocial, string NombreProveedor, string OC, string Facturas, string FormaPago, string FechaRecibido, string FechaPago, string MonedaMXN, string MonedaUSD, string Notas)
    {
        command.Connection = conexion.Connection();
        command.CommandText = "FacturaPagada";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RazonSocial", RazonSocial);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NombreProveedor", NombreProveedor);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OC", OC);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Facturas", Facturas);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormaPago", FormaPago);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaRecibido", FechaRecibido);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaPago", FechaPago);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MonedaMXN", MonedaMXN);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MonedaUSD", MonedaUSD);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notas", Notas);


        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        conexion.CloseConnection();
    }
```

En mi clase CN_Facturas.cs ...

```
public void FacturaPagada(string RazonSocial, string NombreProveedor, string OC, string Facturas, string FormaPago, string FechaRecibido, string FechaPago, string MonedaMXN, string MonedaUSD, string Notas)
    {
        facturaCD.InsertarPagadas(RazonSocial, NombreProveedor, OC, Facturas, FormaPago, FechaRecibido, FechaPago, MonedaMXN, MonedaUSD, Notas);
    }
```

Y en el evento Click de mi button...

```
 string RazonSocial;
        string NombreProveedor;
        string OC;
        string FormaPago;
        string FechaRecibido;
        string FechaPago;
        string MonedaMXN;
        string MonedaUSD;
        string Notas;
        FacturasPagadas pagadas = new FacturasPagadas();
        DataRowView datos = facturasPendientesDG.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        if(datos != null)
        {
            idFactura = datos["Facturas"].ToString();
            RazonSocial = datos["RazonSocial"].ToString();
            NombreProveedor = datos["NombreProveedor"].ToString();
            OC = datos["OC"].ToString();
            FormaPago = datos["FormaPago"].ToString();
            FechaRecibido = datos["FechaRecibido"].ToString();
            FechaPago = datos["FechaPago"].ToString();
            MonedaMXN = datos["MonedaMXN"].ToString();
            MonedaUSD = datos["MonedaUSD"].ToString();
            Notas = datos["Notas"].ToString();
            facturaCN.FacturaPagada(RazonSocial, NombreProveedor, OC, idFactura, FormaPago, FechaRecibido, FechaPago, MonedaMXN, MonedaUSD, Notas);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
        }
```

Mi variable idFactura la declare como global
Mi Stored Procedure...

```
 CREATE PROC FacturaPagada
@RazonSocial NVARCHAR(150),
@NombreProveedor NVARCHAR(250),
@OC NVARCHAR(100),
@Facturas NVARCHAR(100),
@FormaPago NVARCHAR(10),
@FechaRecibido DATE,
@FechaPago DATE,
@MonedaMXN NVARCHAR(100),
@MonedaUSD NVARCHAR(100),
@Notas NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
INSERT INTO Pagadas VALUES(@RazonSocial, @NombreProveedor, @OC, @Facturas, @FormaPago, @FechaRecibido, @FechaPago, @MonedaMXN, @MonedaUSD, @Notas) SELECT RazonSocial, NombreProveedor, OC, Facturas, FormaPago, FechaRecibido, FechaPago, MonedaMXN, MonedaUSD, Notas FROM Pendientes WHERE Facturas=@Facturas
GO
```